# Scala list validSelectValues not updated

Tags: scala, lift

This is my code in a class Building:

```
object province extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, Province) {
    override def dbColumnName = "province_id"

    def selectValues: Box[List[(String, String)]] =
        Full((("0", "")) +: Province.findAll(OrderBy(Province.name, Ascending)).
                map( p => (p.id.is.toString, p.name.is)))

    override def _toForm: Box[Elem] = Full(selectValues.flatMap{
        case Nil => Empty
        case xs => Full(SHtml.ajaxSelect(xs, Full(this.is.toString), v => {
            this.set(v.toLong)
            JsCmds.ReplaceOptions("council_select",
                   councilsList(v).map(c => (c.id.is.toString, c.name.is)), None)
        }))
    }.openOr(<span>{"sin provincias"}</span>))

    private def councilsList(p: String) = p match {
        case id if id != "" =>
            Council.findAll(By(Council.province, p.toLong),
                            OrderBy(Council.name, Ascending))
        case _ => List()
    }
}

// Council
object council extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, Council) {
    override def dbColumnName = "council_id"
    val id = "council_select"

    override def validSelectValues: Box[List[(Long, String)]] =
        Full(((0l, "")) +: Council.findAll(By(Council.province, province),
                             OrderBy(Council.name, Ascending)).
                map( c => (c.id.is, c.name.is)))

    override def _toForm: Box[Elem] = Full(validSelectValues.flatMap{
        case Nil => Empty
        case xs => Full(SHtml.selectObj(xs, Full(this.is), this.set, "id" -> id))
    }.openOr(<select id={id}/>))
}
```

in the edit form, when I change on the list the province, council list is replaced by province filter perfectly, but when i save building, councill is not saved/updated the first time. the next times, it save perfect because the province is seted, until i change province other time... So, when I set a new province, the councill isnt saved, I need to save 2 times, 1 for province, and 1 for council.

I think that the problem is because validSelectValues of object council, is loaded the first time i load the page, and it will be filtering by the province seted, or null list when province is not set... how can I reload the council validSelectValues when i change the province list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your call to `ajaxSelect` with `ajaxUntrustedSelect`. The normal select options in Lift check that the value being submitted is trusted, IE: that it was one of the options available when the page was generated. If you are using javascript or other means to mutate the list, you can avoid that check by using the Untrusted version of the component.

Comment: thanks, but i change ajaxSelect by ajaxUntrustedSelect in province toForm and dont work. The problem is not province, it save all the times well. PRoblem is saving council: when I change province and council list is reloaded, I select a council, and try to save bulding, province is saved, council not. I have to save 2 times, 1 for province, and 1 for council. If i change council without change province, it save perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I have find...

```
object council extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, Council) {
override def dbColumnName = "council_id"
val id = "council_select"

def selectValues: Box[List[(String, String)]] = province.obj match {
   case Full(o) => Full( Council.findAll(By(Council.province, o),
                          OrderBy(Council.name, Ascending)).
            map( c => (c.id.is.toString, c.name.is)))

   case _ => Full((("0","")) Council.findAll(OrderBy(Council.name, Ascending)).
            map( c => (c.id.is.toString, c.name.is)))   
}

override def _toForm: Box[Elem] = Full(selectValues.flatMap{
    case Nil => Empty
    case xs => Full(SHtml.untrustedSelect(xs, Full(this.is.toString), v => {this.set(v.toLong)}, "id" -> id))
}.openOr(<select id={id}/>))
```

}

Comment: A little problem: when i want to set a blank value to council (province without councils), council is not updated to null. how can i solve this¿